# TLS 1.2 mutual authentication certificate based standard

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, packet, mutual

I'm running an analysis on a TLS1.2 mutual authentication certificate-based client-server implementation and I'm wondering if there's a RFC or a reference document covering the handshake process when it comes to mutual authentication between server and client. 
I'm interested in the packets / messages exchange between client and server under the different cases (mutual auth successful vs. mutual auth failing).

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a problem with https://www.google.com/search?q=TLS1.2+mutual+authentication+handshake

Answer (score 3):

The usual TLS RFC's like [RFC 5246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) cover the relevant handshakes already. Just look into the RFC and search for anything related to client certificates.